# Systemfont (San Francisco) and UltraLight

Tags: swift, fonts

```
UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20, weight: UIFontWeightUltraLight)
```

When I'm using this font with `UIFontWeightUltraLight`, it only becomes ultra light when the size is `20` or bigger. What's the reason for this and is there a workaround to get the ultra light with a smaller size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact the “system font” is missing three weights below size 20: Ultra Light, Thin, and Black:

[image: font weights at size 19 and 20]

Antonio Cavedoni discussed this in [WWDC 2015 Session 804: Introducing the New System Fonts](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-804/):

> Both families have two cuts that are called optical sizes, and they are text and display, and I will talk about these in a second. And all of the fonts have six weights for the text families and nine for the display ones.

And later:

> So there are two distinct font families in SF and SF Compact. They are called Display and Text, and they are used at different point sizes. The system automatically switches between the two for you so you don't have to do anything to adopt them.

And later still:

> The system switches between the two at 20 points,

There's lots more in the talk about the differences between the display and text sizes. **You should watch the whole thing before you decide that forcing Ultra Light at small sizes is a good idea.**

Anyway, at size 20 and above, it uses the display optical size, which has all nine weights. Below size 20, it uses the text optical size, which has only the six weights Light through Heavy.

You can force use of the display optical size by asking for it explicitly by name. However, the name isn't documented and Apple clearly didn't intend for you to use it, so they could change the name in the future, or even make the font entirely unavailable by name in a future release. Using this in a real app is a bad idea and you should definitely not do it.

```
let font = UIFont(name: ".SFUIDisplay-Ultralight", size: size)
```

Result:

[image: display font weights]

Comment: Thanks, excellent explanation. Guess I won't be using ultra thin for the smaller sizes.